# Elasticsearch - Filter dashboard based on bounds drawn in map by key to other index pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have 2 index patterns and 2 data views in Kibana, one for each index pattern.
one of the index pattern is geolocation with map view panel in Kibana.
All the points has ID (numeric) which may exists in the other index pattern (which is not geolocation).
Now I would like to filter points using the 'Draw bounds to filter data' tool and I wish it will filter the other index by the same key that found within the map boundaries.

is it possible to join between the 2 data sources? I tried term join in the layer setting but it didn't work (actually it removed all the geo points in the map)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `geolocation` data in all indices that you want to filter. Otherwise when you `Draw bounds to filter data` the index without `geolocation` will be outside of the filter.

I recommend to use [enrich processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-enriching-data.html) and merge two index into one.

You can find [an example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/match-enrich-policy-type.html) in this link.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.
I tried to use enrich processor, but in my case there's multiple geopoints per one key. so the process enrich has issue: cannot be changed from type [dense_vector] to [float]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, if you can share mapping, sample data from source and enrich index I can help you more